# Certificate services will not start with "server is offline" error

Tags: certificates, server

I have a subordinate CA. The Enterprise root service was uninstalled from the network by accident and then migrated to a new box using the same key. This new server has a different server name. It worked for a few days and now the subordinate has two Delta-CRL locations and one is expired with an incorrect location pointing at an incorrect domain controller. How can I resolve this? The service will not start.

Comment: What product are you using?  This may be better suited to ServerFault but don't worry, we'll migrate it if it is.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about network/server administration and is better suited to [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: This question is about using crypto which is listed in the approved topics.

Answer (score 2):

When AD Certificate Services starts up, it *insists* on validating its own certificate (the subordinate CA certificate). This entails verifying that the CA certificate has not been revoked, by obtaining the CRL referenced from the [CRL Distribution Points](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.13) extension found in that certificate. If the CRL have been moved, and not up-to-date CRL can be found at these location, then the validation will fail, and the service will refuse to work.

At this point, you have the choice between four strategies to recover the situation:

1. Put back the root CA, or more precisely the CRL issued by the root CA, where the subordinate CA expects them to be. By default, in an Active Directory context, CRL will be in a location which depends on the machine name (start the "Sites and Services" tool, activate the "show the services node", then find the "CDP" node). These are AD objects, which can be copied and moved (an AD object is "just" a collection of attributes) so you could script that process to do it automatically.
2. Push the CRL from the root CA into the local machine store of the subordinate CA, so that Certificate Services may see them even if it does not find them at the designated distribution point. This can be done with the GUI (`mmc.exe` console), or programmatically ([CertAddCRLContextToStore()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376011%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))(I have done the latter, invoking the Win32 function from a piece of C# dynamically recompiled from a PowerShell script...).
3. Renew the subordinate CA certificate, reusing the same name and key, but with a new certificate with CRL Distribution Points pointing to the location where the root CA now publishes its CRL.
4. Scrap the subordinate CA and install a new one, reusing the same name and key. This is a variant of the previous strategy, but more thorough. To avoid losing control of all previously emitted certificates (these are still valid and you still want to be able to revoke them), you would have to push them back into the new CA using [`certutil`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732443.aspx) (`certutil -importCert` to reimport a certificate, `certutil -revoke` to make the CA again aware of a past revocation). This is high and desperate surgery; don't do this until all other strategies have failed.

Generally speaking, ADCS has been designed so that it integrates quite deeply into Active Directory structures, and the complete ramifications are intricate and poorly documented. Things work "magically" by default, and you discover why when you do a seemingly unrelated change and they break.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. How can I copy the crl like you suggested in 1.?  Also shouldn't the enterprise root ca be offline?

Comment: A root CA _should_ be offline, but its revocation information must still be made available to certificate consumers, i.e. published online one way or another. When the root CA is offline, there must be a regular, _manual_ publication process to get the CRL from the offline machine, and transfer them (e.g. with a USB stick) to another machine which is online, typically a Web server, or an Active Directory server.

Comment: I would like to try your suggestion in 2. What are the steps using the mmc? Thanks very much for your help.